# Acceso al File Provider denegado en Android

Tags: java, android, content-provider

Tengo una actividad associada para la apertura de un tipo de archivo, usando algún explorador de archivos, al selecionar el documento y que se abre con mi app, a veces recibo:

> Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading nextapp.fx.fileprovider.FileProvider uri content://nextapp.fx.FileProvider/storage/emulated/0/Documents/Untitled4.md from pid=31631, uid=10442 requires the provider be exported, or grantUriPermission()

El código donde salta:

```
public static String getFileName(Context context, @NonNull Uri uri) {
    String displayName = null;
    String uriString = uri.toString();
    if (uriString.startsWith("content://")) {
        try (Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null)) {
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                displayName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));
            }
        }
    } else if (uriString.startsWith("file://")) {
        File myFile = new File(uriString);
        displayName = myFile.getName();
    }
    return displayName;
}
```

Al intentar resolver el content provider: `context.getContentResolver()`

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Y el permiso otorgado Android M> de `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` establecido por el usuario dinamicamente.

Se debe otorgar otros permisos para poder usar proveedores de contenido?

**Definición de content provider**

```
<provider
    android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
</provider>
```

#### Solución??

Buscando por [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24467696/android-file-provider-permission-denial) he solucionado el error, antes de obtener el nombre del archivo, en interceptar el intent de apertura:

```
List<ResolveInfo> resInfoList = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resInfoList) {
    String packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
    grantUriPermission(packageName, markDownFile, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
}
```

Entiendo que ese código lo que hace es otorgar permiso de lectura y escritura a todas las apps instaladas puedan usar la `uri` del content provider.

¿Pero hay alguna forma que solo otorgar el permiso al uri concreto del content provider, pero solo para la app que pide abrirlo?

Comment: en la linea  String packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName; revisa si estas obteniendo el packagename correcto.

Answer (score 0):

Para aplicaciones que apuntan al API 23+ es necesario manejar los [permisos dinámicos](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting), fue un cambio de diseño importante por el cual los permisos declarados en el manifest no se otorgan al momento de descargar sino que se piden al momento de ser usados. Para solucionar el problema tienes 2 opciones:

1. Cambiar el target API de tu app a 22, no es recomendado ya que te deshabilita a usar las funcionalidades modernas de la plataforma. pero te saca del problema rápidamente.
2. Utilizando la estrategia de permisos dinamicos, cada vez que se accede al uso de un [permiso "peligroso"](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview#normal-dangerous) deberias:
   Chquear si el permiso fue otorgado y en caso de no, solicitarlo o manejar el rechazo:

   ```
       if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity, Manifest.permission. << Permiso >> ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) { //Permiso no otorgado//Ya se negó el permiso antes, insistir con una explicación de por que se pide el permiso. 
           if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(thisActivity,
                   Manifest.permission. << Permiso >> )) {
               // Mostrar un detalle de por que se pide el permiso
           } else {
               // No se negó el permiso antes, solicitar normalmente.
               ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
                       new String[] {
                               Manifest.permission. << Permiso >>
                       }, requestcode);

               // Este pedido es asincronico, por lo que requestcode sirve para identificar el pedido luego en onRequestPermissionsResult
           }
       } else {
           // Permiso otorgado, usar normalmente
       }
   ```

Con eso envias el pedido de permisos y deberias manejar la respuesta acorde:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
        String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case XXX: {
            // si no se otorgaron los permisos, el array vuelve vacio.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // Permiso otorgado, usar normalmente
            } else {
                // Permiso negado, manejar situación
            }
            return;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: buenas, si lo de permiso dinamico ya lo tengo, lo pondré más claro a la pregunta